# Controller to View via ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is View File here Displaying error for student in list

```
@model IEnumerable<Controller2View.Models.Students>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn btn-default">
       <ul class="list-group">
    @foreach (var std in ViewData["StudentData"] as List<Students>)
    {
        <li class="list-unstyled">
            std.StudentName
        </li>
    }

</ul>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is Controller file which have a list defined and viewdata for transferring data from controler to View. Model also defined well but dont know whu its not working.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
    List<Students> studentList = new List<Students>() {
                new Students(){ StudentId=1, StudentName="Steve"},
                new Students(){ StudentId=2, StudentName="Bill"},
                new Students(){ StudentId=3, StudentName="Ram"}
            };
        ViewData["StudentData"] = studentList;
        return View(studentList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be good to know what exactly is not working. But still 2 things:

1. Either use the view with a model **or** with ViewData.
2. I guess you get a list of 3 items with "std.StudentName", that's because it must read **@std.StudentName**

Comment: i want to use ViewData to transfer data from controller to view

Comment: So modify your code like that:
1) **View**:
a) delete line model IEnumerable<Controller2View.Models.Students>
b) Replace std.StudentName with @std.StudentName (as recommended in my answer)
2) **Controller**: call the view with return View();
Done.

Comment: In List<Students> Displaying namespace error for Students in View File , that is namespace name Students Could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
    var studentList = new List<Students>() {
                new Students(){ StudentId=1, StudentName="Steve"},
                new Students(){ StudentId=2, StudentName="Bill"},
                new Students(){ StudentId=3, StudentName="Ram"}
            };

        return View(studentList);
    }
```

Now, In View use below code

```
@model IEnumerable<Controller2View.Models.Students>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn btn-default">
       <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach (var std in Model)       
        {
        <li class="list-unstyled">
            std.StudentName
        </li>
        }    
       </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully it will works as I am using model directly instead of casting it into list.

Comment: Apply but not showing list data just displaying std.StudentName three Times